# Como guardar una imagen en una carpeta utilizando rutas relativas

Tags: java, html, archivo, servlets, fileupload

Estuve escribiendo este codigo para guardar imagenes en una carpeta, pero el problema es cuando guardo las imagenes. Cuando llego a colocarle la ruta absoluta funciona correctamente, pero encambio si utilizo una ruta relativa , no me funciona.Quisiera saber que debo hacer para obtener la ruta relativa y así poder almacenarla en mi base de datos.

Porfavor si saben o tienen alguna idea escribanla me sería de muchisima utilidad.

```
@MultipartConfig
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part part=request.getPart("Foto");
        File uploads=new File("\\src\\java\\Imagen");

        File file=File.createTempFile("imagen-",".JPG",uploads);
        try(InputStream input=part.getInputStream()){
            Files.copy(input, file.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
             }
        }
}
```

alguien que me ayude porfavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borré mi respuesta anterior porque no era correcta.

En [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application) hay varias opciones de como hacerlo, pero lo importante a destacar es lo siguiente:

La ruta es absoluta, está fuera del proyecto, y del contexto de la webapplication.

Fuera del proyecto:

Fuera de la carpeta `src` porque esa carpeta no va a existir cuando se deploye el war en un application server.

Fuera de otra carpeta dentro del proyecto:
Porque los archivos subidos deben permanecer independientemente de que la carpeta de la aplicación en el application server (ejemplo `/.../webapps/miappweb`) sea eliminada o reemplazada por una nueva versión.

Absoluta: Quitando la opción de que la carpeta sea parte de estructura de la aplicación web y asumiendo que no se sabe como es la estructura de directorios donde está el application server, hacer la ruta absoluta da la flexibilidad necesaria para designar cualquier carpeta como destino de los archivos subidos.

Por último dentro de las opciones que se muestran en esa pregunta me gustan las opciones donde la ruta se configura desde fuera de la applicación como setear una variable de entorno, o definir una propiedad en el application server que pueda ser leida en la aplicación de forma de no tener que recompilar para setear el directorio definitivo. Pero las otras opciones también son válidas e incluso más convenientes dependiendo de otos factores como si se trata de una aplicación interna donde se conoce de antemano el servidor destino.

Comment: Osea a lo que vas es que la unica manera de guardar mis imagenes, es con una ruta absoluta?, pero entonces como la hago portatil, si lo quiero subir a un servidor , y luego digamos, quiero cambiar de servidor, los directorios almacenados en el sql no funcionarian,entonces que hago?, soy un poco novato en esto, y quisiera aprender, utilice el link que me enviaste para justamente hacer lo que hice arriba , pero no encuentro en su totalidad como guardarlo, nisiquiera un codigo avanzado , o un proyecto para guiarme, la verdad es que ya no tengo ideas :c

Comment: Lo podes hacer portatil separando la ruta en una parte absoluta (desconocidea), y una parte relativa (a la ruta absoluta). En la base de datos guardas solo la parte relativa. La parte absoluta la fijas como parámetro de la aplicación y la podés modificar cuando sea necesario.  Con que aplication server estas trabajando? Tomcat?

Comment: hola otra vez , si estoy trabajando con tomcat, sabes estuve intentado hacer justo lo que me estas diciendo , con la diferencia que estoy almacenando los nombres de las imagenes en las bases de datos , el directorio de la carpeta no lo almaceno, solo agarro y lo coloco de manera absoluta , mi logica es crear una pequeña ventana que te pida la url donde vas a agregar la carpeta de imagenes, de esa manera mi url o mi directorio cambiaria las veces que yo quiera ,bueno eso es en teoria , por que cuando intento mostrar las imagenes en la tabla no se deja :c , por más que les envio la ruta T.T

Comment: sobre lo de guardar la ruta relativa , luego la concateno con File.separator algo así supongo . y tengo que crear como una ventana que pida ingresar la ruta , o bueno me hago una idea que algo así es lo que debo de hacer verdad?

Comment: amigo por cierto, intento agregar una imagen en src por medio del directorio, pero no lo acepta :c, que puede estar saliendo mal, no tengo errores en los paquetes dao, me parece que en jsp las cosas cambian un poco, a diferencia del html puro , que puedo hacer?. cree un paquete llamado imagenes, donde se guardan mis imagenes valga la redundancia , pero el problema viene cuando intento llamarlo por medio de directorio en el <img src=" "> ya intente varias cosas, que puede ser?

Comment: Como el archivo está fuera del ambito del servidor no lo podes referenciar directamente con una url, porque no hay url para el archivo. Para descargar el archivo tenes que mandar una referencia al archivo (http://ejemplo.com/archivo/123 o http://ejemplo.com/archivo/miimagen.jpg) e interpretar y fabricar la respuesta leyendo el archivo de la carpeta donde está guardado. Esto igualmente corresponde a una pregunta diferente: "Como descargar un archivo con un servlet". (O ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, pero apesar de lo que me dijiste no le encuentro una solución, es como que cada vez que logro pasar una linea se vuelve más complicado y casi ya no encuentro información al respecto en la web , lo que quería hacer era un catalogo el cual la imagen lo guardara en una carpeta y su ruta guardarlo en la base de datos , tan simple como usar un e.getRuta() y colocarlo en el src , pero no funciona así :c , lo peor es que ninguno de mis profesores me enseña, o bueno quizas no sepan. Bueno hasta aquí llegue, es curioso pero me salió obteniendolo de una base de datos

Comment: pero todo el mundo me dice que obtenerlo de una base de datos es una mala practica, si sabes donde puedo descargar un proyecto similar para poder guiarme sería genial, me canse de que me expliquen , prefiero ver un proyecto el cual me pueda guiar, ya que ya no se trata tanto de logica , si no de parametros a seguir creo yo, o tal vez no se programar :c

Comment: No tenes ninguno de estos problemas si el catálogo y sus imagenes son estáticas (parte del war). Todo este tema deriva de la subida de archivos con el servlet y tener que almacenarlos en algún lado donde no se pierdan cada vez que haces un nuevo deployment. No es algo trivial. La respuesta que vinculé al principio menciona varias formas en la que se puede hacer, con ejemplos, y no son complejas, pero necesitas un conocimiento básico sobre como trabaja un servlet container / application server y en especial el que estás usando.  Seguí adelante, en poco tiempo esto te va a resultar familiar.

Comment: entendí que no puedo enviar los datos de forma directa a un servlet , ya que este trabaja directamente con el servidor de tomcat , por lo que si coloco imagenes// no existira , ya que en el servidor de tomcat no trabaja directamente con los recursos del proyecto que estoy trabajando, entonces que puedo hacer para que trabajen directamente, justamente por eso digo, avanzo una linea y luego se hace más complicado. Redundando en pocas palabras , creo una carpeta en webpages y facilmente puedo llamarlos en un jsp, pero si lo creo en los packages practicamente es imposible

Comment: amigo gracias , lo intente revisando lo que me enviaste y me llego a salir, tuve que leer todos los foros que me enviaste, la verdad ciertas cosas me confundian, pero en si es combinar varias cosas de las que estan ahí. Tal vez no quiero sonar fastidioso, gracias a ti me salió enserio, pero por que cuando las imagenes se cargan y aparecen en la pagina web, cuando le doy actualizar aveces me aparecen solo 3 imagenes y las otras 2 no, u otras veces todas las imagenes aparecen y cuando le doy actualizar como que solo aparecen 3 y 1 deja de aparecer como si fuera aleatorio, como si fuera un bug

Answer (score 0):

[image: Esta es la pagina web para mostrar las imagenes]

[image: este es el servlet para agregar]

[image: este es el servlet para mostrar la imagen ya que recupero la imagen de la carpeta]

[image: Este es el jsp para agregar la imagen en una carpeta]

Coloque el programa de forma que el servlet sea mi pagina web de recuperacion de las imagenes para que así pueda llamarlo en el src por medio de nombre

Comment: esta es la respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: asi es , esta es el problema ,era que no puedo colocarle rutas relativas a una pagina web, ya que estas no tienen que ser portatiles, a fin de cuentas se suben a un server como una pc, entoncesel teniendo eso bien en mente , ya pude realizar mi proyecto